# Django messages/notification if connected model doesn't exist / has changed

Tags: python, django

I have a `Profile` model, which is a `OnetoOne` relation to the `User` model.

I would like to tell the users that their profile is not complete, and ask them to fill in certain details dynamically.

For example, I have a `Location` model which is a `OneToOne` to the `Profile`.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # some fields e.g. name 

class Location(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # longitude = ...
    # latitude = ...
```

After user signup, we do not yet have the `location` instance connected to `profile`. What I would like to display, is a django-message/error bar at the top, instructing the user to complete the profile if the `profile` doesn't have the `location` attribute.

I'm not sure how I should proceed:
One way, I thought is to add the `completed_setup` boolean field to the `Profile` class. If user now decides to delete `location`, we will also update this field and set it to `False`.

```
{% if profile.completed_setup %}{% else %}
<p>Finish Building Your Profile</p>
{% endif %}
```

Another way would be to have the following in the template:

```
{% if profile.location %}{% else %}
<p>Finish Building Your Profile</p>
{% endif %}
```

I'm looking for the most efficient and proper way to do this, since I have more connected models (not just location).

Comment: Why not make `completed_setup` a method that checks the existence of all necessary fields/related instances?

Comment: @schwobaseggl This is possible, but then that would imply that almost every page load checks 3-4 models, where as, if I update `completed_setup` as a field, I only look up one model (but then I have to create signals)

Comment: I'm trying to see the most efficient way to approach this problem

Comment: I see, this constitutes, however, a denormalisation of your database. You will then have to manually maintain the integrity of that field's state. I would leave such optimisation to the end of development ;)

Comment: @schwobaseggl I see, but even development, for example if I need to list all completed profiles: I would have to first get list of all `profiles` and the iterate over them checking `for p in profiles: if p.completed_setup`, which is way more computationally expensive. Unless there is a way to call a method on a group of instances?

Comment: Sorry ahead of time I didn't see the comments before I started an answer. Based off of what you are saying here. The first solution is out with the DoesNotExist, but the property in the second with related names will work great for one item at a time and it can be directly referenced in a template. The last for filter based on completed is going to be the most efficient as possible. I could be wrong, but you might be able to use completed setup property since we already prefetched the related names. I have never tested this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a property added onto the Profile model instead of a new field. Since the completed_setup is most likely a computed value, you can use the getter of a property to provide the value of completed_setup. There are two options. First, you could attempt to get the OneToOne fields and if it doesn't exist then return False. You could do this for multiple fields

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    # some fields e.g. name
    @property
    def completed_setup(self):
        try:
            Location.objects.get(profile_id=self.id)
            AnotherModel.objects.get(profile_id=self.id)
        except (Location.DoesNotExist, AnotherModel.DoesNotExist):
            return False
        else:
            return True

#template
{% if profile.completed_setup %}{% else %}
    <p>Finish Building Your Profile</p>
{% endif %}
```

You could also use the related name to check if it exists probably more reliable than above. This can also be done for multiple fields.

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    # some fields e.g. name
    @property
    def completed_setup(self):
        if self.location and self.another_onetoone:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Location(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, related_name='location', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # longitude = ...
    # latitude = ...

#template
{% if profile.completed_setup %}{% else %}
    <p>Finish Building Your Profile</p>
{% endif %}
```

I saw on one of your comments of the question you want to be able to run queries on multiple groups. Here is a way to do that. I recommend doing this with prefetch_related on the queryset if you pass it as I've done with objects.all(). The first solution is not ideal for a large database. The second is good for one object. The best solution for filtering on completed_setup is below.

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    # some fields e.g. name
    @property
    def completed_setup(self):
        if self.location and self.another_onetoone:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @classmethod
    def filter_completed_setup(cls, queryset=None, completed_setup=True):
        match_ids = []
        if not queryset:
            queryset = cls.objects.all().prefetch_related('location', 'another_onetoone')
        else:
            queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('location', 'another_onetoone')
        assert queryset.model is cls, "queryset must be of class Profile"
        for p in queryset:
            if completed_setup:
                if p.location and p.another_onetoone:
                    match_ids.append(p.id)
            else:
                if not (p.location or p.another_onetoone):
                    match_ids.append(p.id)
        return cls.objects.filter(id__in=match_ids)

Profile.filter_completed_setup(queryset or None, completed_setup=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the class method, I will look at this shortly